# How to build an Android app that listens and reacts to gestures globally?

Tags: android, gesture, samsung-mobile, multi-touch, samsung-mobile-sdk

I recently bought Galaxy Tab S8 and noticed that it's builtin gesture controls are pretty terrible.

I'd like to build my own system to react to two and three finger swipes to do things such as going back in the app and switch between apps no matter what app is in the foreground.

Is such thing possible? If it is, how to get started?

Comment: An app has no means to do this. Were you planning on building custom firmware for this tablet?

Comment: No I would not want to build a custom firmware. All I want to do is to listen to and react to gesture events globally.

Comment: That falls under "tapjacking malware attack". You want to be able to observe touch input and allow some of it (things unrelated to your gestures) to pass through to underlying apps (so they actually work). That has been blocked for a decade.

Comment: So there's not even any permission I could give to it? And not even in dev mode? I'm not necessarily interested in publishing it in app sotre. How does apps such as this: https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.goodlock?langCd=en does it? It controls different gesture areas globally and is an app.

Comment: "So there's not even any permission I could give to it?" -- you can build an accessibility service. Whether you will be able to accomplish your objectives that way is unclear. "It controls different gesture areas globally" -- the page that you linked to seems broken, insofar as it does not describe the app.

Comment: The app I linked is to adjust or override Samsungs gesture controls. It is made by Samsung essentially, but is still just an app. accessibility service sounds like an interesting option, that is kinda what I'm after, after all.

Comment: "It is made by Samsung essentially, but is still just an app" -- Samsung can do things on Samsung hardware that ordinary developers cannot do.